# OpenNetCF.IoC can not hit start in SmartClientApplication

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf, opennetcf.ioc

I'm using [OpenNetCF's IoC framework](http://ioc.codeplex.com) and the code in my Program class looks like:

```
public class Program : SmartClientApplication<Container>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [MTAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            if (!string.Equals(RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.EnglishName, "New Zealand") ||
                !string.Equals(TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName, "New Zealand Standard Time"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please set your regional and time zone settings to New Zealand.");
                return;
            }

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;

            new Program().Start();
        }

        static void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've copied OpenNETCF into my solution and I was expecting when Program().Start() was called it would jump to the start method here so I set a break point on it:

```
public abstract class SmartClientApplication<TShell>
    where TShell : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This method loads the Profile Catalog Modules by calling GetModuleInfoStore which, unless overridden, uses a DefaultModuleInfoStore instance.
    /// It then creates an instance of TShell and calls Application.Run with that instance.
    /// </summary>
    public void Start()
    {
        // load up the profile catalog here
        IModuleInfoStore store = GetModuleInfoStore();

        Start(store);
    }
```

Strangely it never hit the break point.

I thought this was strange so I clicked in Program to navigate to the definition from the inheritance reference to SmartClientApplication.

This opened a completely different file to the one I was expecting and looks like:

```
using OpenNETCF.IoC;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenNETCF.IoC.UI
{
    public abstract class SmartClientApplication<TShell> where TShell : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        protected SmartClientApplication();

        public virtual void AddServices();
        protected virtual void AfterShellCreated();
        public virtual IModuleInfoStore GetModuleInfoStore();
        public virtual void OnApplicationRun(Form form);
        public virtual void OnModuleLoadComplete(string moduleName);
        public void Start();
        public void Start(string profileCatalog);
    }
}
```

Same name but the contents don't seem to contain any implementation. When I see where its location it is something like:

C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\7212$OpenNETCF.IoC.UI.dll$v2.0.50727\OpenNETCF.IoC.UI.SmartClientApplication.cs

so that explains why it didn't hit the breakpoint but what I want to know is why it's even looking at this crazy file and not the one it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have multiple copies of the source and the PDBs on your development machine.  If you built one of the IoC samples, then copied the folder wholesale, including the obj and bin folders, over to your app's path this could happen.

The solution (or at least a start to is) is to do the following:

- Remove the IoC reference(s) from your project
- Build to generate an error
- Open Explorer and delete all obj and bin folders from your solution tree
- Re-add the reference(s)
- Rebuild